# compilation fails for nested boost::variant of fusion pairs

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14

Following code fails to compile on gcc 4.9.2 with boost 1.64:

```
#include <boost/fusion/support/pair.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

#include <string>

namespace bf = boost::fusion;
namespace bm = boost::mpl;

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    using L2_t = boost::variant<bf::pair<bm::int_<1>,char>>;
    using L1_t = boost::variant<bf::pair<bm::int_<1>,L2_t>>;
    L1_t result;
}
```

while I think, it's legal.

Error message starts with:

```
/home/vagrant/.conan/data/boost/1.64.0/conaned/master/package/b06f2a498643ee1d889c6aea8e0e21d3cac9f57c/include/boost/fusion/support/pair.hpp: In instantiation of ‘constexpr boost::fusion::pai
r<First, Second>::pair(const boost::fusion::pair<First, Second2>&) [with Second2 = boost::variant<boost::fusion::pair<mpl_::int_<1>, char> >; First = mpl_::int_<1>; Second = char]’:          /home/vagrant/.conan/data/boost/1.64.0/conaned/master/package/b06f2a498643ee1d889c6aea8e0e21d3cac9f57c/include/boost/type_traits/is_constructible.hpp:33:45:   required by substitution of ‘tem
plate<class T, class Arg, class> static boost::type_traits::yes_type boost::detail::is_constructible_imp::test1(int) [with T = boost::fusion::pair<mpl_::int_<1>, char>; Arg = const boost::fus
ion::pair<mpl_::int_<1>, boost::variant<boost::fusion::pair<mpl_::int_<1>, char> > >&; <template-parameter-1-3> = <missing>]’
```

Compilation succeeds when I change one of pair's key value to make them different.

How to solve this problem? I use those pair key values to serialize/deserialize, so having them same values on different levels is important for me.

Comment: Looks like it starts working in gcc 5.2: https://wandbox.org/permlink/o4IpZbyohgECH7kO

Comment: Right! Thank you for reminding about online compilation, I forgot. That was silly not to check there.

Comment: If you look at the change logs (especially which bugs were resolved), there are a lot of C++11 bugs being fixed in the late 4.9 and early 5.x versions.   Even some missing features still being implemented.  Thank you for posting a complete example that made it trivial to copy/paste into an online compiler.

Answer (score 1):

As xaxxon said, this works starting with gcc 5.2.